# Centering tabs inside superfish navbar

Tags: css, navbar, centering, superfish

Superfish navbars are great, but when you are looking at the rightmost tab, the second tier navbar starts at the far left. So if there are only a few tabs, it looks off-center and the user has to mouse all the way to the left. How can you center the tabs inside the superfish navbar?

Comment: Can you please include a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable code in your question?

Comment: I would not have asked this question until I did research on it. I have searched on navigation centering, nav-bars, superfish, etc. I have found many places where you center the navigation BAR, but not the tabs WITHIN the bar. Trying to get the code here...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found the appropriate line to change in the css:

```
.sf-navbar > li > ul > li {
float: left;
```

}